# How to detect a packet in Linux

Tags: detect

I need to detect the arrival of every UDP packet from a particular source address. Is there any way I can detect this particular packet coming into my Ubuntu machine?
My aim is to generate a response packet for every UDP packet received from that particular source address.

Comment: Install a sniffer

Comment: But I need to have a trigger. Installing wireshark can help me identify incoming packet, but what I need is a trigger. With this trigger, I can generate response packets.

Comment: I would've written a  simple server-client program ...

Comment: I would have stolen/adapted the UDP server from my "Programming Perl" book.

Comment: Is such a code available online for free? I do not know how to code it